# No match for argument: pgadmin4 in Red Hat 8

Tags: redhat, pgadmin-4

I am trying to install pgadmin in Red hat 8 by

```
sudo yum install pgadmin4
```

However:

```
No match for argument: pgadmin4
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Red hat version:

```
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Version:        8.0
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Postgres repository first.

```
dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

then run following

```
dnf install pgadmin4
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! But after your first command, I got this "Package pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
" Then by your second command, i got the same result as before: "No match for argument: pgadmin4
Error: Unable to find a match
"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if still needed but i had the same problem.
i didn't find pgadmin4 repository on dnf, but it's still available on yum.

you just need to setup this repo :

```
sudo rpm -i https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/pgadmin4-redhat-repo-1-1.noarch.rpm
```

then install Pgadmin4 with yum :

```
# Install for both desktop and web modes.
sudo yum install pgadmin4

# Install for desktop mode only.
sudo yum install pgadmin4-desktop

# Install for web mode only.
sudo yum install pgadmin4-web
```

got this on pgadmin website https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/

if it can help